# Can not find <iostream> when using it in a .y file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, yacc

I am new to Xcode, and I am trying to migrate a c++ application which compile in win32 cygwin using g++ an bison to Xcode.

I did search the website for information, before asking question

I have been having issues since the beginning, I narrowed it down to the following. This is my steps:

1. Create a new console application in Xcode
2. This is a C++ application, with no Auto Reference Count
3. A main.cpp file is created
4. Comment out main procedure
5. Create new file, simpleYACC.y
6. Copy the following into the .y file:

   ```
   %{
       #include <iostream>
       //
       int yylex (void);    
       void yyerror (char const *);
   %}

   %token NUM

   %%
   exp:;
   %%

   int yylex (void)
   {
       return 0;
   }

   void
   yyerror (char const *s)
   {

   }

   int main (void)
   {
       return yyparse ();
   }
   ```
7. Trying to build it
8. Getting the following error:

CompileC /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Simple.tab.o /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/DerivedSources/Simple.tab.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Source Code/SimpleYACC"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/SimpleYACC-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/SimpleYACC-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/SimpleYACC-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/SimpleYACC-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Simple.tab.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Simple.tab.dia -c /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/DerivedSources/Simple.tab.c -o /Users/brendanbosman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimpleYACC-dglitxihrkprgndyxanispqjpbmc/Build/Intermediates/SimpleYACC.build/Debug/SimpleYACC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Simple.tab.o

/Source Code/SimpleYACC/SimpleYACC/Simple.y:6:14: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
    #include 
             ^
1 error generated.

I am a bit clue less on this error, and why I am missing  >

I would really appreciate any help

Brendan

Comment: I fixed your code formatting. When you put code into a numbered list, you must indent it four spaces from the alignment of the list, not four absolute spaces. Didn't you notice that the code looks bad?

Comment: I did, but did not know how, will read up on this

Answer (score 1):

You're including a C++ header file in C source. Bison generates a C program. If you want to generate a C++ parser, take a look in the Bison manual under the section *Parsers Written in Other Languages*.